# Magento2 - Search preview not showing up

Tags: magento2.3, template, search

I have a custom template file in which I am trying to call search block as showing up in header.

***In header the search is rendering through***

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml("topSearch"); ?>
```

***In my custom phtml file, I have included the search template as***

```
<?php  echo include ($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml')); ?>
```

This shows up the search field and it's working but it's not showing up the preview.

Means preview result are forming which I can see in devTools but I feel like the preview html is not forming which is not showing the preview div on frontend even it's forming.

Please help.

Comment: do you want to show suggestions right showing on ajax fire?

Comment: @sandip search preview results are forming but the issue is that the preview is not showing up. I feel like I have called the search incorrectly.  Like using $this-getChildHtml("topsearch"); is working in header so I called the search block as shown above in my custom file . Maybe that could be the reason.

Comment: How can I call the childhtml search block in my custom template file content ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code into a specific layout XML file of the custom module.

Do not render the file from `Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml` file.

**File: Custom_Module/frontend/layout/nameofyourlayout.xml**

```
<body><referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="content.search" as="contentSearch" template="Custom_Module::form.mini.phtml" />
</referenceContainer></body>
```

**File: Custom_Module/frontend/templates/form.mini.phtml**

```
<?php
/** @var $block \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template */
/** @var $helper \Magento\Search\Helper\Data */
$helper = $this->helper(\Magento\Search\Helper\Data::class);
?>
<div class="block block-search">
    <div class="block block-title"><strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Search')) ?></strong></div>
    <div class="block block-content">
        <form class="form minisearch" id="customsearch_mini_form" action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($helper->getResultUrl()) ?>" method="get">
            <div class="field search">
                <label class="label" for="search" data-role="minisearch-label">
                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Search')) ?></span>
                </label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input id="search"
                           data-mage-init='{"quickSearch":{
                                "formSelector":"#customsearch_mini_form",
                                "url":"<?= $block->escapeUrl($helper->getSuggestUrl())?>",
                                "destinationSelector":"#search_autocomplete_custom",
                                "minSearchLength":"<?= $block->escapeHtml($helper->getMinQueryLength()) ?>"}
                           }'
                           type="text"
                           name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($helper->getQueryParamName()) ?>"
                           value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($helper->getEscapedQueryText()) ?>"
                           placeholder="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Search entire store here...')) ?>"
                           class="input-text"
                           maxlength="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($helper->getMaxQueryLength()) ?>"
                           role="combobox"
                           aria-haspopup="false"
                           aria-autocomplete="both"
                           autocomplete="off"
                           aria-expanded="false"/>
                    <div id="search_autocomplete_custom" class="search-autocomplete"></div>
                    <?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="actions">
                <button type="submit"
                    title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Search')) ?>"
                    class="action search"
                    aria-label="Search"
                >
                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Search')) ?></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```